# MySQL LIKE pattern matching returning empty set when it should be returning values

Tags: mysql, sql, wildcard, sql-like

I have a table structured like below (real data replaced with dummy data):

```
tableName 
+-----------+----------------+
| code      | description    |
+-----------+----------------+
| A         | text here      |
| b         | blah blah      |
| c         | sdfsdfsdfsdf   |
| d         | sdfsfkaljdaklj |
| e         | asdkjasdlkjasd |
| f         | adskljalkdj    |
| g         | asdjalkd       |
| h         | askdjavsd      |
+-----------+----------------+
```

I am trying to do the following command:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE description LIKE '__[aeiou]%';
```

I expect this select statement to return all results from the table where the third character in the description is a, e, i, o, or u.

However, I am getting 0 results for the about query. I know for a fact that valid results which match this pattern (3rd character is a, e, i, o or u) exists in the table.

What is wrong with my query?

Comment: I dont think mysql LIKE accepts range [] so it interprets it as a literal string starting with [.

Comment: From your link `The other type of pattern matching provided by MySQL uses extended regular expressions. When you test for a match for this type of pattern, use the REGEXP and NOT REGEXP operators`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regular expression instead of a SQL Server style `LIKE` pattern:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE description REGEXP '^..[aeiou].*$';
```

EDIT:

For those who don't read documentation thoroughly, the documentation says:

> The other type of pattern matching provided by MySQL uses extended
>   regular expressions. When you test for a match for this type of
>   pattern, use the REGEXP and NOT REGEXP operators (or RLIKE and NOT
>   RLIKE, which are synonyms).
>
> The following list describes some characteristics of extended regular
>   expressions:

The list of features, such as `[` and `]` is in this list.  The standard for `LIKE` has only two wildcards, `%` and `_`.

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid I don't understand why `LIKE` is not working when it claims in the docs to support this feature? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: @Prefix . . . Read the documentation more carefully.  The list of supported features is after this sentence:  "The following list describes some characteristics of extended regular expressions:" -- and these use `REGEX`.

Comment: Ahhh, that explains it :) apologies, been a long day.

Comment: @Prefix It is RLIKE or REGEXP (not "REGEX").

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL the '_' character is a not part of the extended regular expression class and can not be used as such. use RLIKE to use regular expressions